# Error with cmap from a matplotlib defined list of colors in Folium - choropleth map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I'm triying to pass a customize list of colors to my choropleth map with geopandas.explore, but i get the error:

***UnboundLocalError: local variable 'binning' referenced before assignment***

if I specified a given list of colors ex: **cmap= 'Blues'**, it displays with no problem

I copy the code below

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.colors
import folium

color_list= matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom', [ "#e1f2f2", "#A8DCDC", "#115F5F"]) 

ventas_map= data.explore(column='ventas', scheme='Quantiles', cmap= color_list, tiles= 'OpenStreetMap', k=5, legend_kwds={'caption': 'ventas[$]','colorbar': True ,'scale': False}, name= 'ventas')
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Looks like a bug - will look into it more deeply when I'm less tired tmr and raise issue / provide work arounds and work on PR if necessary.

Comment: Hi Rob! could you find something? thks

Comment: I have - been busy fixing bugs in geopandas...  I'll commit a PR to fix soon and then a workaround.   There is no very simple workaround, need to go back to basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to do this, I defined the color list with the following function, and then use the name list I gave between *'color_list'* in the cmap atribute in geopandas.explore function

```
def colors2cmap(*args, name=None):
"""Create a colormap from a list of given colors.

Parameters:
    *args: Arbitrary number of colors (Named color, HEX or RGB).
    name (str): Name with which the colormap is registered.

Returns:
    LinearSegmentedColormap.

Examples:
    >>> colors2cmap('darkorange', 'white', 'darkgreen', name='test')
"""
if len(args) < 2:
    raise Exception("Give at least two colors.")

cmap_data = [matplotlib.colors.to_hex(c) for c in args]

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(name, cmap_data)
plt.register_cmap(name, cmap)

return cmap }
```

And called the function:

```
 colors2cmap("#e1f2f2", "#A8DCDC", "#115F5F", name='color_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted this is a bug that I have patched and created a [PR 2590](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2590)

This will need to go through merge and release process.  In interim you can download and use version of function from my patch which has been committed to GitHub

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.colors
import folium
import numpy as np
import requests
from pathlib import Path

# download and import patched module
file_url = "https://github.com/rraymondgh/geopandas/raw/explore_cmap_scheme/geopandas/explore.py"
with open(Path.cwd().joinpath(file_url.split("/")[-1]), "w") as f:
    f.write(requests.get(file_url).text)
import explore

gpd.explore._explore = explore._explore

r = np.random.RandomState(42)
data = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
data["ventas"] = r.uniform(1, 30, len(data))

color_list = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "custom", ["#e1f2f2", "#A8DCDC", "#115F5F"], 7
)

# use patched module, note change from data.explore() to explore._explore() with first
# argument being geodataframe
ventas_map = explore._explore(
    data,
    column="ventas",
    scheme="Quantiles",
    cmap=color_list,
    tiles="OpenStreetMap",
    k=5,
    legend_kwds={"caption": "ventas[$]", "colorbar": True, "scale": False},
    name="ventas",
)

ventas_map
```